# Does this bar make sense?

Tags: lyrics, rap

My boyfriends a rapper, he showed me something he’d written and we’re disagreeing over one of the bars. He’s adamant that it makes sense but I’m telling him it doesn’t.

*“They used to laugh and look at Chris like he’s a hocus pocus and now they really wanna know from what I wrote in folders”*

I said hocus pocus sticks out and doesn’t make sense in that context. He said he means people used to look at him as a joke or a ‘hocus pocus’ because he wanted to rap but I’m saying it’s literally a phrase like ‘abra cadabra’ and therefore makes no sense as a description of somebody, and doesn’t mean what he’s trying to say.

Can anyone back me up or tell me why I’m wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about music, but English language comprehension.

Comment: So where can I ask it? 

Comment: Reddit, Quora, Facebook… anywhere answers don't have to be factual, every opinion counts, & where topics don't have to be strictly adhered to.

Comment: [ELU mod here] This question wouldn't fit on [English.se] or [ELL.se] as it is either, although you **could** ask whether *hocus pocus* has ever meant *joke.* But you need to do your own research with a couple of dictionaries first (and put that in any question you ask).

Comment: It's also a great number by Focus.